# Firebase Timestamp returns with wrong date - Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I'm trying to get the Timestamp value from firestore (using Firebase Functions), and I´ve successfully done it localy with the toDate() method of Timestamp, and moment library.

```
moment(doc.data().EndDate.toDate())
```

But when I deploy my code to firebase and test the function, somehow the toDate() returns a Date with 1 less hour than the saved timestamp on firebase. I suppose it is transforming my date to UTC, since I'm in UTC+1, and the Timestamp is also stored with UTC+1 in firestore, but I don't know how to reliably get the timestamp date as is in firestore, regardless of timezones.

If someone knows why this happens or has any idea how to solve it it would be great.

Comment: What exactly do you get when you call `console.log(doc.data().EndDate.toDate())`? And how is the date stored in the first place? Anyway, the key to understanding this is that `July 13, 14:17 GMT+1` is the exact same timestamp as `July 13, 13:17 GMT+0`. So the main question is whether your firebase stores the correct timestamp. Once that is established, we can focus on displaying it in the appropriate timezone.

Comment: I get `2020-07-19T23:00:00.000Z` and the firestore date is 2020-07-20T00:00:00. The date is stored using `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(subEndDate)`, which subEndDate is a javascript date.

Comment: Yes, I'm using this to compare two dates, and since the returned date is less one hour, it also means it's less one day in this case, and the comparison no longer works. I've used toString() too, but again, only works when served locally

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to compare? To be clear, you're most likely creating the problem by comparing the dates the wrong way. Midnight in your timezone is 23:00 the previous day UTC, so these dates are probably exactly the same, it's just that your browser converts one of them to local time, and a string comparison is unsuitable to compare Date objects.

Comment: Yes, I used the moment isSame: `if(moment(subEnd).isSame(moment(today))` and today is a new Date. Yes that's true, it is the same time but when the timezones comes to action, it isn't. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**All timestamps in Firestore are stored in UTC.**  If you see something different in the Firebase console, that's just your browser formatting it for your local timezone.

In JavaScript, all Date objects are also represented in UTC.  If you format that as a string, you will again possibly get a different representation based on your local timezone.

If you write code that computes values using dates or timestamps, **you should perform all your computations using UTC**.  This is the pretty much all computing systems want to deal with dates.  When it comes time to format the date for display to an end user, only then should you take timezone into account, and present something according to the user's preferences.

Comment: Yes! I was saving the wrong date to firebase, thanks for setting me in the right path! For future reference, or if anyone has the same trouble as me, I used the Date.UTC() constructor to build a Date with UTC format, (check the docs if you have any trouble),  so when it is saved in firestore it remains UTC. I was building a date just with new Date(), and that has the local time attatched to it, and it will save with your current timezone. Not sure if it's the optimal or the most semantic solution, but it works great.