# Using firestore timestamp to save the date of birth

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firestore timestamp for storing the date of birth of a user.
I want to store the date as 6/25/1982 using
`firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(6/25/1982));`

Date is visible in firebase document as June 24, 1982 at 5:00:00 PM UTC-7 in USA and June 25, 1982 at 05:30:00 AM in India.

How to make the date same while showing the date of birth.

Comment: It might be out of topic, but, why not save it as a string directly with the value desired?

Comment: can you check these stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62876786/firebase-timestamp-returns-with-wrong-date-javascript), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69112229/is-firebase-server-timestamp-value-same-all-over-the-world) & [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68771155/firestore-timestamp-todate-returns-wrong-utc-date)